# No article before a noun

Tags: nouns, articles, speech

I've recently noticed that in some cases, the definite article before a noun is dropped. I assume this is only characteristic of spoken interaction. The first time I noticed this was while watching a gameplay on Youtube. This is the sentence that caught my attention:

*Family pic used to hang here. I can't actually remember which one.*

As far as I'm considered, it there should be an article before picture, either "a" or "the".

Here's another case which I noticed today while watching Mr. Robot on Prime Videos (Amazon):

*He definitely got it from radiation at the company he worked at, though I couldn't prove it.*

*Now he's dead.*

*Company's fine, though.*

Since "company" is known from previous context and is mentioned again, I would expect to see:

*The company's fine, though.*

Initially I thought that the article is pronounced carelessly so as not to be audible but now I actually think it's just ommitted. Am I correct?

Sorry if this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's all fine.

Here is something which might help you understand the problem.

Michael Swan, Practical English Usage, 3rd ed. point 179(3)

'In informal English we often leave out unstressed words at the beginning of a sentence if the meaning is clear. The words include articles, possessives, personal pronouns, auxiliary verbs and the preparatory subject there

*(The) Car's running badly*

*(My) Wife's on holiday*'

[image: Michael Swan Practical English Usage, ed. III]